# Nvidia Energy Consumption Watcher

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

The idea was to write a context manager that would calculate energy consumption for the given machine learning pipeline running on a GPU. It does it by polling the current power consumption using the nvidia bindings library pynvml.

The energy consumption is then calculated in KWh.
The total pipeline consumption is the sum of the second-wise consumption over all the working time.

$$
\text{energy_consumption} = \text{current_power} * 1 / 3600 * 1/1000
$$

Where 1/3600 — one second in hours, 1/1000 — to transform watts to kilowatts.

There are two display options: live updates in a terminal or by writing a log file.

Programmatically it works in the following way:

Upon entering the context manager `PowerWatcher` spawns a new process which executes the `_watch_power` function. This function polls the GPU every 1 second, until it receives the SIGKILL or SIGTERM. In order to handle the signal properly, e.g. to close the log file, it uses the `_GracefulKiller`, which redefines the standard behavior: instead of termination, it just sets the `self.kill_now` flag to True. At the end of the block inside the context manager, it terminates the process with `_watch_power`. Finally, the total amount of energy, consumed by the pipeline is returned from the manager with the help of the `_ValueContainer`.

Project repo: https://github.com/WGussev/PowerWatcher/tree/dev

There are three questions, which I find particularly important:

1. Is my way of passing information between the Processes correct?
2. Is it OK to use the custom object `_ValueContainer` to pass a value from my context manager?
3. Is the project structure appropriate, taking into account that I plan to distribute the package via PyPI?

Usage example:

```
with PowerWatcher() as pw:
    ...
    do your ML-stuff
    ...
print(pw.value)  # get the overall consumption
```

```
"""
PowerWatcher -- python3 context manager to log power consumption of any ML-pipeline running on a Nvidia GPU.
"""
import signal
import time
from datetime import datetime
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
from multiprocessing.connection import Connection
from pathlib import Path

from pynvml import nvmlDeviceGetPowerUsage, nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex, nvmlInit


class _GracefulKiller:
    """
    SIGINT and SIGTERM catcher.
    Modifies process interruption behaviour: the kill_now flag is set to True instead of actually exiting the process.
    taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499497/how-to-process-sigterm-signal-gracefully
    """

    kill_now = False

    def __init__(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.exit_gracefully)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.exit_gracefully)

    def exit_gracefully(self, signum, frame):
        """
        Set kill_now flag.
        :param signum: required by signal.signal, not used directly
        :param frame: required by signal.signal, not used directly
        :return:
        """
        self.kill_now = True


class _ValueContainer:
    """Container to return values from a context manager."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0

    def update(self, value):
        """
        Update stored value.
        :param value: a value to store.
        :return:
        """
        self.value = value


def _watch_power(logfile: Path = None, sender: Connection = None, display: bool = True):
    """
    Poll GPU and log/display current power consumption.
    Update frequency: every 1 second.
    :param logfile: logfile path (the file will be created/overwritten).
    :param sender: sender-end connection.
    :param display: display consumption in terminal.
    :return: None
    """
    if (logfile is None) and (display is False):
        raise ValueError('You should log and/or display consumption')

    total = 0
    killer = _GracefulKiller()

    nvmlInit()
    handle = nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(0)

    if logfile is not None:
        f = open(logfile, 'w')
    while not killer.kill_now:  # exit gracefully
        power = int(nvmlDeviceGetPowerUsage(handle)) / 1000  # strangely nvidia outputs milliwatts
        total += power / 3600 / 1000  # convert to kWh
        if display:
            print(f'\r{datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")} {total:.5f} kWh so far', end='')
        if logfile is not None:
            f.write(f'{datetime.now()} {power}\n')
        time.sleep(1)
    if display:
        print('', end='\n')
    if sender is not None:
        sender.send(total)


class PowerWatcher:
    """
    Context manager to track pipeline energy consumption.
    Update frequency: every 1 second.
    with PowerWatcher() as pw:
        ...
        your pipeline
        ...
    pw.total  # get results
    """

    def __init__(self, logfile: Path = None, display: bool = True):
        """
        :param logfile: logfile path.
        :param display: consumption display toggle.
        """
        self.logfile = logfile
        self.display = display
        self.total = _ValueContainer()

    def __enter__(self):
        """Run upon entering the context."""
        return self.start()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        """
        Run on context exit.
        :param exc_type: required by Context Manager syntax but not really used here
        :param exc_value: required by Context Manager syntax but not really used
        :param traceback: required by Context Manager syntax but not really used
        :return:
        """
        self.stop()

    def start(self):
        """Start manually."""
        self.recv_end, send_end = Pipe(False)
        self.watcher = Process(target=_watch_power, args=(self.logfile, send_end, self.display,))
        self.watcher.start()
        return self.total

    def stop(self):
        """Stop manually."""
        self.watcher.terminate()
        self.total.update(self.recv_end.recv())
```

Project tree:
[image]

Comment: @Peilonrayz Sure, thank you, I've added some edits explaining the project. Hope, it'll be helpful

Comment: Thank you for the added description, that's great! :D